# Visual Studio modifies Oracle Queries before execution, causing them to fail

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, visual-studio-2017

I'm running Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 7.  Since part of my day involves Oracle work, I added an Oracle db to Server Explore in VS.  Works fine!.  Tried a simple query:

```
SELECT 1 AS ONE FROM DUAL
```

which works fine.  Then just for fun I tried this:

```
SELECT trunc(sysdate - 1)
FROM DUAL
```

I found that VS rewrites this as:

```
SELECT        trunc("sysdate" - 1) AS EXPR1
FROM            SYS."DUAL"
```

Which fails, unsurprisingly.  Anyone know how to stop VS from rewriting my queries?

Answer (score 1):

Please try changing `SYSDATE` to `CURRENT_DATE` in your query and see if it helps.

Comment: yes that works but that's not really the point.   This is just a toy query to see if I can, in general, write a valid Oracle query from Visual Studio.  If I take the stock example from the Oracle site for SYSDATE, it fails on Visual Studio, since VS is adding double-quotes around SYSDATE.  see here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions172.htm.  Here's another example: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions186.htm.  If you copy the sample and try to run in in VS, VS again adds double-quotes so that the query fails.

Comment: FWIW I think this is the same issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30693971/sql-query-works-in-pl-sql-but-not-in-visual-studio?rq=1 which was not solved.

Comment: Filed bug report here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/275767/visual-studio-modifies-oracle-queries-before-execu.html

Comment: @user1443098 I am not an expert but I think VS supports the standard ANSI SQL just fine, but is quoting the vendor-specific keywords that it's unaware of.

Comment: Right, that's the problem. When the query is going to a foreign DB, VS should leave the query as is, since it can't make any assumptions.